# Create contour of given points using MKPolygon in iPhone

Tags: iphone, algorithm, google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3

I have various number of points each time, and I want to draw contour from them. So I need to draw polygon using only extreme points. Is there any ready to use solution?

EDIT:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232672/drawing-isotherm-linesor-contour-using-java-given-specific-points if u could find a solution visit this nd help please

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the [convex hull of a set of points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Implemented using the [google maps API v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull.asp)

Comment: I looks like You are right. But do iOS SDK provide such method?

Comment: Are you using the google maps API v3? If so, it shouldn't depend on anything else.

Comment: Then we need more specific information about your application.  Where to the points come from?  Replace the loop that creates an array of random points with a loop that loads your points (or replace it with the fixed array of points).